# How to properly join a few Media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a situation and I decide to use `media queries`.
The `html`code:

```
...
   <span class="logotext-n">n</span>

    .
    .

   <span class="logotext-u">u</span>
...
```

`Css` implementation:

```
...
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
        .logotext-n {
          color: #f1ecd6;    
          font-family: "arial black", sans-serif;
          font-weight: 900;
          font-size: 210px;
          text-transform: lowercase;
          letter-spacing: -18px;
              }
}

        .
        .

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
        .logotext-u {
          color: #f1ecd6;    
          font-family: "arial black", sans-serif;
          font-weight: 900;
          font-size: 210px;
          text-transform: lowercase;
          letter-spacing: 0;
              }
}
...
```

At this point I was wondering, is there any possibility to join these `css` properties using a single `@media screen`? Thanks

Comment: The media query is the same.. Just put the code for `.logotext-u` and `.logotext-n` in the same media query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, just put it together

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
      .logotext-n {
          color: #f1ecd6;    
          font-family: "arial black", sans-serif;
          font-weight: 900;
          font-size: 210px;
          text-transform: lowercase;
          letter-spacing: -18px;
       }

      .logotext-u {
          color: #f1ecd6;    
          font-family: "arial black", sans-serif;
          font-weight: 900;
          font-size: 210px;
          text-transform: lowercase;
          letter-spacing: 0;
      }
}

        .
        .
```

Comment: That was so easy, I didn't find that example until now.Thank both of you guys !  Pepo_rasta, @Andy Holmes